# How do I get to show Gaussian Kernel for 2d? (opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, gaussian, gaussianblur

I am using this:

```
 blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst,(5,5),0)
```

And I wanted to show the kernel matrix by this:

```
print(cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize=(5,5),sigma=0))
```

But I am getting a type error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

If I only put 5, I get a 5x1 matrix. Isn't the blur kernel 5x5? Or am I missing on something fundamental?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gaussian kernel is separable. Therefore, the kernel generated is 1D. The `GaussianBlur` function applies this 1D kernel along each image dimension in turn. The separability property means that this process yields exactly the same result as applying a 2D convolution (or 3D in case of a 3D image). But the amount of work is strongly reduced. For your 5x5 kernel, the 2D convolution does 25 multiplications and additions, the separable implementation does only 5+5=10. For larger kernels, the gains are increasingly significant.

To see the full 2D kernel, apply the `GaussianBlur` function to an image that is all zeros and has a single pixel in the middle set to 1. This is the discrete equivalent to the Dirac delta function, which we can use to analyze linear time-invariant functions (==convolution filters).

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the 2D kernel by calculating the outer product of the 1D kernel by itself. This can be done using the `numpy.outer()` method.

However, there's little practical purpose for this other than visualizing the kernel. For actually applying a Gaussian blur, use `cv2.GaussianBlur()` as it is highly optimized.

Answer (score 4):

To get the 5x5 Gaussian kernel first we can form a 7x7 Numpy array with only one 1 in the middle.

```
img=np.zeros((7,7))
img[3,3]=1
img
```

The result of the code is

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Then apply gaussian blur:

```
img1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
img1
```

The result is:

```
array([[0. , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,0.        , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.00390625, 0.015625  , 0.0234375 , 0.015625  ,0.00390625, 0. ],
       [0. , 0.015625  , 0.0625    , 0.09375   , 0.0625    ,0.015625  , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.0234375 , 0.09375   , 0.140625  , 0.09375   ,0.0234375 , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.015625  , 0.0625    , 0.09375   , 0.0625    ,0.015625  , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.00390625, 0.015625  , 0.0234375 , 0.015625  ,0.00390625, 0. ],
       [0. , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,0.        , 0. ]])
```

The nonzero numbers are the Gaussian kernel. We can confirm that the sum of the numbers are 1:

```
np.sum(img1)

1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in this example:
[taken from https://theailearner.com/tag/cv2-getgaussiankernel/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZwpd.png)
We can get the dot product of the gaussian kernel with itself transposed.
First we get the 1d kernel:

```
k = cv2.getGaussianKernel(kSize, -1)
```

Then we can restore its original form before normalization just from the fact that the first element is always originally equals 1:

```
k /= k[0,0]
```

Now we can get the dot product as mentioned:

```
print(k @ k.T)
```

If you want it summed up to 1 (normalized), divide it by its sum:

```
kernel = k @ k.T
kernel /= kernel.sum()
print(kernel)
```

Comment: This general concept is correct, but the dot product yields a scalar, not a matrix, you are thinking of the outer product. The division you do is not necessary, the outer product of a normalized kernel with itself yields a normalized kernel. Also not sure why `k[0,0]` should be 1?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what the OP needed. The other answers were also correct, but this is a little simpler and straight to the point if you're looking for a quick answer.

```
import cv2
import numpy

oneD_kernel = cv2.getGaussianKernel(5, sigma=0)
twoD_kernel = oneD_kernel*oneD_kernel.T

print(twoD_kernel)
print(twoD_kernel.sum())
```

and it returns:

```
array([[0.00390625, 0.015625  , 0.0234375 , 0.015625  , 0.00390625],
       [0.015625  , 0.0625    , 0.09375   , 0.0625    , 0.015625  ],
       [0.0234375 , 0.09375   , 0.140625  , 0.09375   , 0.0234375 ],
       [0.015625  , 0.0625    , 0.09375   , 0.0625    , 0.015625  ],
       [0.00390625, 0.015625  , 0.0234375 , 0.015625  , 0.00390625]])

1.0
```

The sum of the 2D kernel also returns 1.0, in case you're wondering.